# Super-String and Anti-Particle

Tags: superposition

I'm afraid this is quite basic question . 
What I learned from the String theory is that the theory unify the Path-integral, 
Superposition Principle, and commutation relation .
In that context , I wondered whether the Anti-Particle can be described by the similar way the  Superposition Principle is expressed by the string theory .
How can the anti-particle be described by the String Theory ?

Comment: It is not clear why you have a question. Both particles and antiparticles are described by their mass, spin, and other quantum numbers and are already classified into SU(3xSU(2)xU(1) multiplets (/supermultiplets). The theory just has to display the group symmetries and there is no problem in the description because the particles/antiparticles will fill the appropriate slots.

Comment: Not my downvote, but: most of the leading edge theories are fantastically complicated and even to ask a coherent question requires considerable knowledge of the area. If I'm maligning you I apologise, but your post gives the impression you're trying to ask a relatively complicated question concerning a subject you know little about. As a result the question doesn't really make sense, and even it were answerable you probably wouldn't know enough about the subject to understand the answer. This is not intended as an insult - I would describe myself in the same way - but I do think you would ...

Comment: ... do better to go off and start reading around the area. Then come back to us with more targetted questions.

Comment: Ah, string theory: where even the non-answer "it's a lot more complicated than you might have thought" doesn't fit into 600 characters :-)

Comment: It seems I had to add that I'm the beginner learner of the String theory .

Comment: >The theory just has to display the group symmetries and there is no problem in the description because the particles/antiparticles will fill the appropriate slots.

Ok , thanks !